# Get Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Duration; when getaccesstoken google credentials in android

Tags: android, kotlin, access-token

I'm trying getAccessToken gg credentials in viewmodel and I get error:

> Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Duration;

I searched on gg but not find any useful information. Please help if you know. Thank you very much. Here is my code:

```
class NotificationViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {

    val header = MutableLiveData<HashMap<String, String>>()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            header.postValue(getRemoteMessageHeaders(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader()))
        }
    }
}

@Throws(Exception::class)
fun getAccessToken(classLoader: ClassLoader): String {
    val credentials =
        GoogleCredentials.fromStream(classLoader.getResourceAsStream("credentials.json"))
            .createScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging")
    credentials.refreshIfExpired()
    return credentials.accessToken.tokenValue
}

fun getRemoteMessageHeaders(classLoader: ClassLoader): HashMap<String, String> {
    val header = HashMap<String, String>()
    header[Constants.REMOTE_MSG_AUTHORIZATION] =
        "Bearer " + getAccessToken(classLoader)
    header[Constants.REMOTE_MSG_CONTENT_TYPE] = "application/json"
    return header
}
```

This is error in logcat I got:

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Duration;
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.<clinit>(OAuth2Credentials.java:70)
    at com.trochoinhacai.kubetchat.viewmodels.NotificationViewModelKt.getAccessToken(NotificationViewModel.kt:28)
    at com.trochoinhacai.kubetchat.viewmodels.NotificationViewModelKt.getRemoteMessageHeaders(NotificationViewModel.kt:37)
    at com.trochoinhacai.kubetchat.viewmodels.NotificationViewModel$1.invokeSuspend(NotificationViewModel.kt:20)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.Duration" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.trochoinhacai.kubetchat-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.OAuth2Credentials.<clinit>(OAuth2Credentials.java:70) 
        
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.time.Duration
    
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: Did you found any solution for that? I have this problem too.

Comment: sr, it is long time so I can't remember solution, but it can fix :v